# How can I "undo" a CSS specification for the ::selection attribute

Tags: html, css

I'm using an application framework that includes default CSS styling for `::selection`, but I prefer my browser's default behavior.

In fact, I find I prefer my browser's default behavior to *any* specification for `color` and `background-color` for `::selection`. They are opaque where the default is transparent, and they change the color of the text where the default does not.

My question is: Is there any way to "undo" or "revert" this styling, or is it the case that once the `color` and `background-color` attributes are defined, they can only be overridden with other equally explicit values?

If so, that would seem to be a shame!

Comment: If this is just a html page then you can easily delete the css that you don't want. But if you cannot do that then you can always override it and there is no shame in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just overwrite the properties with the value [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) to set it back to browser defaults:

```
::selection {
    color:initial;
    background:initial;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3NWR/)

Comment: It's worth noting that `initial` isn't supported by *any* version of Internet Explorer, so while it's a great solution for this question it isn't practical for anyone planning to use it in a website

Comment: @KelvinMackay To solve this, you could simply overwrite the properties with the IE defaults, and then overwrite that with `initial` in all supported browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/hZjuC/ .. This works assuming that IE is the only browser that doesn't support `initial`.

Comment: Also note that `initial` sets the value to the default as defined in the spec. This means that any styling that's applied by the browser itself (The User Agent Stylesheet) will not be used. So, you might still end up with colors that don't match what you're used to. For example, in the linked fiddle, in Chrome, the selected text is black when set to `initial`, but is white normally.

Comment: @JoshC Good thinking. You should include that in your answer for posterity